# Angular 9, KeyCloak, ServiceWorker and Edge Browser

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, angular9, angular-service-worker

I am having a big problem as our Angular application is running fine with

- Angular 9.1
- KeyCloak
- and Service Worker

on Safari, Chrome and Firefox. But on Edge the page is staying blank. When I enter private browser mode it works fine, I assume it ignores the Service Worker then.

It first displays the KeyCloak Login page, that works. But after logging in it stays blank.
There's no error in the console.
If I disable the configuration in the angular.json to

```
...
"serviceWorker": false,
...
```

it works really fine.
Do you have any hints on extra configuration or steps to resolve this issue?
PWA has the following version:

```
"@angular/pwa": "^0.901.0",
```

ngsw.config looks like this

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are testing this issue with the MS Edge legacy browser. I suggest you try to make a test with the new MS Edge Chromium browser. I think that you will not have this issue in the MS Edge Chromium browser. You can download it from here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/?form=MA13DE&OCID=MA13DE Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: Yes, it works for me with the new Edge Browser. Any chance to get it work with the legacy one? When looking at https://caniuse.com/#search=service it should work...

Comment: Not sure which exact version of the MS Edge legacy browser you are using for this test? above code is not giving an idea and there is no error which makes it hard to find the cause for the issue. If any latest version available for an update then try to update it and again test the issue.

Comment: There hasn't been an update for the legacy Edge, so I will take this as solved. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer to this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are testing this issue with the MS Edge legacy browser. I suggest you try to make a test with the new MS Edge Chromium browser. I think that you will not have this issue in the MS Edge Chromium browser. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/?form=MA13DE&OCID=MA13DE).